# Fix node positioning for pgfonlayer to prevent shaky gif

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, gif

I'd like to create a gif using tikz. However, using the `pgfonlayer` to create multiple pages results in the nodes being shifted whenever an edge is added between them. This makes the gif very shaky.

Is there a way to "lock down" the 9 nodes, so that arrows between these nodes appear smoothly in a gif?

This is a working example of 2 pages being created, but they are not correctly aligned.

```latex
\documentclass[hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}

\tikzstyle{box}=[rectangle, draw, thick, minimum size=6mm]
\tikzstyle{up_arrow}=[->, shorten >= 1pt, >=stealth',semithick,bend left]
\tikzstyle{down_arrow}=[->, shorten >= 1pt, >=stealth',semithick,bend right]

\begin{document}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[bend angle=45][overlay]
            \node[box] [label=below:{0}] (a0) {a};
            \node[box] [label=below:{1}] (a1) [right of=a0] {b};
            \node[box] [label=below:{2}] (a2) [right of=a1] {c};
            \node[box] [label=below:{3}] (a3) [right of=a2] {a};
            \node[box] [label=below:{4}] (a4) [right of=a3] {d};
            \node[box] [label=below:{5}] (a5) [right of=a4] {d};
            \node[box] [label=below:{6}] (a6) [right of=a5] {c};
            \node[box] [label=below:{7}] (a7) [right of=a6] {a};
            \node[box] [label=below:{8}] (a8) [right of=a7] {c};
            \node[box] [label=below:{9}] (a9) [right of=a8] {d};
            
            \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
                \draw<1-> [down_arrow] [draw=purple] (a6) to (a8);
                \draw<2-> [up_arrow] [draw=blue] (a5) to (a9);
            \end{pgfonlayer}
        \end{tikzpicture}    
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can set the bounding box of the `tikzpicture`. Try adding something like `\useasboundingbox (0,1.25);` right before `\end{tikzpicture}`. This increases the upper bound of the bouding box and should prevent shifting.

Comment: @JasperHabicht Thanks, that almost solves my issue. However, I'm still getting shaking gif when trying to connect nodes from the bottom instead of top (The code in the post was a trimmed down version, I have around 9 edges). Could you please point me to the documentation of `useasboundingbox` so that I can explore other fine tuning options?

Comment: `\useasboundingbox` just takes any path. You can use a rectangle that is large enough to fit all elements of your picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a bounding box that is as large as the picture with both arrows adding something like to your code:

```
\useasboundingbox (-1,-2) rectangle (10,2);
```

You can also make use of the `overlay-beamer-styles` that allows you to make certain paths of the picture invisible or visble on different slides.

```
\documentclass[hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}

\tikzstyle{box}=[rectangle, draw, thick, minimum size=6mm]
\tikzstyle{up_arrow}=[->, shorten >= 1pt, >=stealth, semithick, bend left]
\tikzstyle{down_arrow}=[->, shorten >= 1pt, >=stealth, semithick, bend right]

\begin{document}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[bend angle=45]
            \node[box] [label=below:{0}] (a0) {a};
            \node[box] [label=below:{1}] (a1) [right of=a0] {b};
            \node[box] [label=below:{2}] (a2) [right of=a1] {c};
            \node[box] [label=below:{3}] (a3) [right of=a2] {a};
            \node[box] [label=below:{4}] (a4) [right of=a3] {d};
            \node[box] [label=below:{5}] (a5) [right of=a4] {d};
            \node[box] [label=below:{6}] (a6) [right of=a5] {c};
            \node[box] [label=below:{7}] (a7) [right of=a6] {a};
            \node[box] [label=below:{8}] (a8) [right of=a7] {c};
            \node[box] [label=below:{9}] (a9) [right of=a8] {d};
            
            \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
                \draw[visible on=<1->, down_arrow] [draw=purple] (a6) to (a8);
                \draw[visible on=<2->, up_arrow] [draw=blue] (a5) to (a9);
            \end{pgfonlayer}
        \end{tikzpicture}    
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that the `arrows` library is deprecated and you should probably use the newer `arrows.meta` library.